# Variable undeclared with random in c

Tags: c, variables, random

I don't why it gives me `l` and `col` as undeclared inside this function.

I had written `srand(time(null))` in `main` and I have already used `rand` in other variable in `main` and in this function, it's the second time using it.

```
void joueur_ordinateur(char jeton, int *a) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  do {
    int l = rand() % 9;
    int col = rand() % 9;
  } while (matrice[l][col] == '.');

  matrice[l][col] = jeton;
  for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++)
      copie[i][j] = matrice[i][j];
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < DIMENSION; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < DIMENSION; j++) {
      capture_chaine(i, j, jeton, a);
    }
  }

  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: You have a l and a col variable defined in the block scope of a do-while loop. Their lifetime ends at the end of that scope - at the end of each iteration. You have no variables of the same name in scope when you try to use them. Try moving the definitions before the loop, leaving assignments inside it.

Comment: @Elas, Show definition of `matrice`.

Comment: [Scope rules in C](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scope-rules-in-c/) , this might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

> don't why it gives me `l` and `col` as undeclared inside this function.

`l, col` only exist within the `do` block.

```
  do {
    int l = rand() % 9;
    int col = rand() % 9;
  } while (matrice[l][col] == '.');
```

Define `l, col` at the function beginning.

```
void joueur_ordinateur(char jeton, int *a) {
  srand(time(NULL));
  int l, col;
  do {
    l = rand() % 9;
    col = rand() % 9;
  } while (matrice[l][col] == '.');
```

---

Given "I had written srand(time(null)) in main", no needed for it in `joueur_ordinateur()`.

```
void joueur_ordinateur(char jeton, int *a) {
  // srand(time(NULL));
  int l, col;
  ...
```